# Tech necessary to build a live video chat site?

Tags: video, chat, live

I'm looking to build a live video chat site.  Before writing a project description, hiring a developer, etc., I'm doing a little research on what types of technologies / web development skills are necessary in order to build this type of site.

The site will feature live video and audio for users to be able to chat with eachother, a simple profile which they can fill out, and the ability to filter the types of users they are connected with.

Your feedback is appreciated.

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 1):

Quite a vague question, seeing as it depends on specifically what sort of functionality you will need, but broadly speaking...

For the site itself, you may need any of the following:

- PHP or ASP
- HTML & CSS
- MySQL or some other database
- Javascript

For the video and audio, you could do this in Flash & ActionScript or via a Java applet. If you're going the Flash route then you may need a copy of Adobe Flash Media Server to support live streaming.

Comment: It's not clear how to create rooms dynamically. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894195/creating-live-video-streams-dynamically for a related question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add a bit info about video chat part. 
If you build it based on WebRTC technology, you'll need:

- an XMPP server for signaling to establish the call;
- user authentication server-side solution to authenticate your users;
- STUN/TURN server for routing the calls.

As an alternative, you can try using a ready backend and SDK and concentrate on building UI for your video chat. For instance, you can try [ConnectyCube](https://connectycube.com/) (WebRTC peer-to-peer solution or SFU based one), [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com) (WebRTC) or [TokBox](https://tokbox.com) (WebRTC).