# Creating live video streams dynamically

Tags: java, live-streaming

I'm familiar with publishing/subscribing to predefined live video feeds on Adobe Flash Media Server. **How can I allow users to create new streams dynamically?** Meaning, instead of providing fixed feeds, users click on "Create Feed", enter a name, and then anyone would be able to publish/subscribe to that feed.

I'm not looking for a source-code (though obviously that would be nice). Rather, I'd like to understand what I need to do a high-level to get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

There is an alternative server called [Wowza](http://www.wowza.com/) that lets you do the same thing as Adobe Flash Media Server except that server-side code is written in Java instead of Actionscript or Flex.

Creating new streams (actually chat rooms) dynamically is as simple as creating a new directory `[wowza]/conf/[application-name]` and populating it with `Application.xml` which you can generate on the fly (Application.xml is described by their usual manual).

In other words, you a client simply hits your web server with a request, the request creates the aforementioned configuration files and the client is then free to publish/subscribe to video streams off the new room you just created.

For more information, see the [User Manual](http://www.wowza.com/resources/WowzaMediaServer_UsersGuide.pdf) page 37 (section "Applications and Application Instances").

> Application configuration is defined in an Application.xml file. When an application instance
>   is loaded, it looks in the following locations for an Application.xml file (where [application] is
>   the application name):
>
> ```
> [install-dir]/conf/[application]/Application.xml
> [install-dir]/conf/Application.xml
> ```
>
> The first Application.xml file that's found is used.

Comment: thanks for sharing the above information, I am trying to do something similar and got stuck. Can you help me out - after we create a new stream, how can we connect this newly created stream to an `Application Instance` and by choosing its `MediaCaster` type as `LiveRepeater` ? Thanks in advance :)